# Jquery how to find only the first occurance

Tags: jquery

I have a few text inputs on a page & a button (well, an `<a>`) next to each input. On click I want to target the closest text input to the `<a>` that is clicked and add the text from the `<a>` into the closest text input area to the end of the text input. My code below does bring the `<a>` text over, but it brings the clicked `<a>` text over into ALL the text inputs. Can you wonderful folks help me limit it to ONLY the actual closest text input to the `<a>` clicked?

```
$('#somestuff').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var aTagText = $(this).text();
    var textboxtext = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').focus();
    textboxtext.val(textboxtext.val() + aTagText );
    textboxtext.focus();
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector) selector like,

```
var textboxtext = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]:first').focus();
```

Also you can short your code like,

```
$('#somestuff').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // use if href is specified in anchor tag, and the page is reloading
    var aTagText = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]:first')
           .focus().val(function(index,value){
              return value + aTagText; 
           });
});
```